# How eclipse validates build.xml files?

Tags: eclipse

Where can I find dtd, xsd or whatever, that eclipse uses to validate ant build.xml file?
**EDIT:**
Actually eclipse is validating build.ini for referential integrity and I am interested to know how is it doing so. Is it using schematron or there is some more elegant way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come there is no Apache Ant xml schema definition or DTD for build scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417458/how-come-there-is-no-apache-ant-xml-schema-definition-or-dtd-for-build-scripts)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be [no official dtd](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#dtd) (this link provides information why not and how to create an incomplete version). If you google for `ant.dtd` you will find information on this topic and also a link to an unofficial [work-in-progress](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/AntDTD) version.

So there must be more eclipse magic (*or whatever*) in validating/parsing the build.xml - I unfortunately do not know about it.